# O que vocês têm na cabeça?

Tags: debate, winterbash-2014

Eu mesmo respondo: nada. Calma, calma... Não quero ofender ninguém não. É que está chegando o fim do ano, e com ele a breve oportunidade de usarmos chapéus nos nossos avatares por alguns dias.

### Hein?

Quem participou do beta privado ou usa o SO original há mais de um ano já deve saber do que eu estou falando. Para incentivar a participação nos sites da rede do meio de dezembro ao início de janeiro, a Stack Exchange promove o **Winter Bash**. Durante o evento, temos a oportunidade de colocar um chapéu nos nosso avatar, e ganhamos novos chapéus ao completar certas tarefas. O funcionamento é bem parecido com o das [medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges). Veja por exemplo os [chapéus da edição do ano passado](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/).

### Como participar

A participação é opcional, e precisamos decidir se o nosso site quer ou não participar do Winter Bash. E mesmo nos sites participantes, ninguém é obrigado a usar chapéus, nem a ficar vendo chapéus por todo o site. Funciona assim:

- Somente usuários logados podem ver e usar chapéus.
- Mesmo para quem está logado, existe uma opção "odeio chapéus" que desliga o Winter Bash para o seu usuário.
- **O Winter Bash 2014** irá de 15 de dezembro de 2014 a 4 de janeiro de 2015.

### Particularidades do SOpt

- É bem provável que certos recursos ligados ao Winter Bash não tenham tradução para o português.
- Os nomes dos chapéus não estarão traduzidos, mas poderemos propor traduções aqui no meta. Alguns serão difíceis de traduzir, pois os nomes são trocadilhos em inglês ou são baseados em referências culturais dos EUA.
- O tema de vários chapéus, assim como o próprio nome do evento, faz referência ao inverno, que no hemisfério norte é agora. Os portugueses não devem estranhar isso, já que é inverno na Europa, mas aqui no Brasil digamos que bonecos de neve, gorros e cachecóis não fazem muito sentido nesta época do ano.

### Concluindo

Vocês querem que o SOpt participe do **Winter Bash 2014**? Deixe sua opinião como comentário ou resposta abaixo! Eu acho o evento bem divertido, e realmente alavanca a participação até nos dias mais parados do ano, como 25 de dezembro e 1 de janeiro. E também sei de pelo menos um usuário que vai querer participar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não vejo a hora de ver esse avatar usando um chapéu. Vai ser um verdadeiro meta-chapéu!

---

### UPDATE 2014-12-10

Considerando a alta pontuação da resposta pró-chapéus em relação às demais, já avisei aos administradores da rede que nosso site quer participar!

Comment: "bonecos de neve, gorros e cachecóis não fazem muito sentido *nesta época do ano*" euri

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Hehehe, nem percebi o que escrevi. É verdade, no Brasil não fazem sentido *nunca*! Pelo menos não os bonecos de neve...

Comment: Esse Winter Bash só dura durante esse evento, ou depois de conquistá-los ele continuará valendo pra sempre?

Comment: Depois de 4 de janeiro tudo some, @Gammeth.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas não fica nada nem pra usar-mos na edição 2015?? ;-;

Comment: Acho que não, @Gammeth. Não tenho certeza, mas talvez dê pra consultar os chapéus que você ganhou em edições anteriores.

Comment: vamos lá participar, eu quero um redhat :D

Comment: Tem razão @bfavaretto aqui faz todo o sentido, até porque está bem frio, 8ºC as 9h.

Comment: Um chapéu num chapéu :D

Comment: Haha, legal.  Vamos então chapelar.

Comment: Vamos então *"apanhar bonés"* !

Comment: Bah... Vai ser legal

Comment: E que venha dia 15.

Comment: O chapéu que venha rápido que aqui estão 2ºC de manhã.

Comment: redhat, redhat, redhat!!!

Answer (score 30):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Por que não? Vamos entrar no clima e brincar!

Comment: @Orion não vale você já usa o meu preferido, redhat :P

Answer (score 7):

[image: Que tal esses?]

Answer (score 4):

Hehehehe, O que vocês acham agora?

@bfavaretto tah bom assim?

O Chapeu não aparece aqui no meta.. =/

Comment: Hehehe, gostei!

Answer (score 3):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Usar chapéu nesse calor? Sem chance!

Comment: Mas chapéu também protege do sol!

Comment: A ideia é dar +1 nesta resposta se você for contra o Winter Bash?

Comment: Isso, seria para votar nela se você for contra

Comment: Mas como não??? **http://www.waldeneffect.org/20120612solarcoolinghat.jpg**

Answer (score 2):

Eu tenho cabelo. Pracas.

Ia ser massa ter uma peruca e uma cartola do Slash.

Comment: Um boné do slashdot seria mais temático.

Comment: @bfavaretto Também!

Answer (score 2):

Acho que vai ser muito legal! Bora participar!

Answer (score 0):

Nessa época no Brasil estaremos no verão e uma boa parte da população entra em férias e tem outros planos (que não envolvem ficar perto do computador).

**Penso que aproveitaríamos melhor o *Winter Bash* no nosso inverno**, já que ninguém gosta de brincar fora de casa nessa época. **(ಠ‿ಠ)**