# Vamos ter Winter Bash 2015?

Tags: debate, winterbash-2015

Esse ano vamos ter Winter Bash?  :D :D
Não sei se esse evento é tradição na rede (espero que sim!), mas o do ano passado foi bem maneiro.

Se você não faz ideia do que é ou não lembra, leia aqui: [O que vocês tem na cabeça?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2288/o-que-voc%C3%AAs-t%C3%AAm-na-cabe%C3%A7a)

---

**Edição:**

Para termos chapéus, basta a comunidade querer.

Se concordarmos, essa edição vai durar do dia 14 de dezembro até 3 de janeiro do ano que vem.

#### Uma pequena introdução

Winter Bash é um evento que premia os usuários com chapéus virtuais ao se realizar determinadas tarefas ou atingir conquistas no site. Esse chapéus podem ser vestidos nos avatares dos usuários que os conquistaram, deixando o avatar engraçado (pelo menos essa é a intenção).

Os chapéus não são vistos por quem não é membro da comunidade, e aqueles que odeiam chapéus podem desativar para não ter que ver os outros se divertindo com chapéus bobos por aí :)

Depois do fim do evento, todos os chapéus desaparecem e não se pode mais usá-los. Os chapéus ganhos em uma determinada edição do evento não pode ser usado em edições subsequentes.

Comment: A primeira pergunta é: Queremos Winter Bash? :)

Comment: Acho que seu comentário deveria ser transformado em uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Certo, depois de respondida ela eu respondo essa aqui :D

Comment: Eu já sinto algum frio nas orelhas.

Comment: Eu acho que podemos usar esta pergunta mesmo pra ver se a comunidade quer ou não o WB. @math

Comment: @bfavaretto tava pensando nisso tb

Comment: Se quiserem, editem a pergunta ai.. Eu não sou bom com essas edições.

Comment: Pergunta editada, agora só precisamos de imagens engraçadas para representar o "sim" e o "não".

Comment: Precisa ter aqueles 'desafios' malucos também, como, acesse o site durante 31/12 - 23:59 a 01/01 - 00:05, acesse o chat no dia do natal :D

Comment: @rray ah sim, sempre tem, fora os chapéus secretos que do nada você ou outros ganham e todo mundo fica doido para descobrir como que foi

Comment: Eu já guardei o meu do ano passado: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5UUg.png

Comment: Winter is coming!

Answer (score 23):

## Sim, eu quero chapéus

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ou que tal essa? http://adoptadogesorensen.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/2/11828599/4238566.jpg rs

Comment: redhat is here.

Comment: Viu isto, @Math? [How do I interact with people?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270223/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo não tinha visto, bem legal. Agora que estou mais decepcionado ainda por você ter votado contra os chapéus D:

Comment: @Math, pra este caso específico, estou na categoria [*"grumpy old users"*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321030705/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/clowns-vomit-rainbows.png) :P

Comment: @brasofilo *só pra esse caso*???? Tem certeza? `:D`

Comment: @Gabe, não tenho certeza, mas também não vou afirmar nada extra que me comprometa ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Alguém aqui falou em "Chapéus"??? Por favor, não!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 Eu não quero :/ - Apesar que é opcional mesmo :p

Comment: Por que alguém não quereria? Desculpe-me a curiosidade, mas você poderia dizer porque não quer, @GuilhermeNascimento ? Pois uma coisa é não usar, outra é não querer que os outros usem...

Comment: @carla aqui tem um exemplo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2327/3117 em resumo, o site as vezes fica meio _louco_, pessoal votando descontroladamente para tentar cumprir os objetivos dos chapéus

Comment: @carla o exemplo do Math explica bem meus motivos, não sou totalmente contra, mas são os pequenos problemas que vem junto que me fazem não querer. ;P

Comment: Hmmm...faz todo sentido. Não tinha pensado por esse lado.

Comment: Esse gato está mais engraçado que o outro, +1 nessa resposta.Wow haha

Comment: Eu vou negativar quem estiver com foto de gato usando chapéu.